# How do I access PropertyChanged event from a static property?

Tags: silverlight

I have static Property a like this :

```
    public static int AverageDiarrheaB
    {
        get { return averageDiarrheaB; }
        set
        {
            averageDiarrheaB = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AverageDiarrheaB");

        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

While running I am getting this error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CareMapGlobals.OnPropertyChanged(string)'.

How to rectify this... please help

Thanks

Sandeep

Comment: +1 just for using `diarrhea` in code :)

Comment: I have updated with a fix just for your current situation, so that you will not need to change all the other uses of your static property. *Please note I am not condoning your method of accessing static properties from everywhere and strongly suggest you find a better pattern.*

Answer (score 0):

### Simple answer:

Remove 'static' from `public static int AverageDiarrheaB` and from `public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

### Longer answer:

The key is in the name `PropertyChanged`... it applies to *properties* of objects.

You can only sensibly have property change events on properties attached to an object (e.g. class properties). Otherwise the "name" parameter would be meaningless as there is no object with that property name.

If you just want to share a single setting across all instances, you can have a static field that is accessed by a non-static setter and getter.

e.g.

```
private static int averageDiarrheaB
public int AverageDiarrheaB
{
    get { return averageDiarrheaB; }
    set
    {
        averageDiarrheaB = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AverageDiarrheaB");
    }
}
```

*If you do need static access to an entire object search for singleton patterns and access a single instance of an object that way instead.*

### But ignoring all that, this will work (tested):

... your code will "work" if you replace *this* with null and make the other changes shown to make `OnPropertyChanged` static as well:

```
private static int averageDiarrheaB;
public static int AverageDiarrheaB
{
    get { return averageDiarrheaB; }
    set
    {
        averageDiarrheaB = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AverageDiarrheaB");

    }
}

public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public static void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The consequences of consuming the static `PropertyChanged` event are that you will not have an object reference. Give it a try and see if it works "enough" for your purposes.

Given the extreme misuse of the `PropertyChanged` event in your code I would suggest using a new event name instead :)

Comment: "still not working" does not really show what the problem is when 3 different options were suggested. Please post your complete code so we can spot the problem. :)

Comment: i can't Remove 'static' from public static int AverageDiarrheaB because in all the pages i am accessing this property as classname.AverageDiarrheaB. and i put Null insted of "this". but not working